# Add extra tooltip in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a question of adding extra tooltip info in Highchart.

My current highchart tooltip only displays  [1,2] and [4,5] but in my data set I have third value besides x and y which are 3 and 6.

[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...]

I want to add 3 and 6 into my tootip. What should I do next?
[image]

Comment: I would recommend you post the JavaScript for your Highcharts configuration - it will make it easier to recommend a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) property to customize the tooltip content. For example:

```
tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            return 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b> and the value for z is ' + this.point.z;
        }
    },
```

And since I'm referencing `point.z` in the callback function, my `series`'s `data` array should also identify a `z` property:

```
series: [{
        data: [{y:29.9,z:'test 1'}, {y:71.5,z:'test 2'}, {y:106.4,z:'test 3'}]
    }]
```

Of course, you do not need to name your property `z` - you can name it whatever you want.

I have created a fiddle demonstrating the implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/cn9z1be5/1/